# Is there a way to accept a single character as an input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

New to programming, so my apologies if this is dumb question.

When utilizing the Scanner class, I fail to see if there is an option for obtaining a single character as input. For example,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The above code allows me to pull the next line into a string, which can then be validated by using a while or if statement using a.length() != 1 and then stored into a character if needed.

But is there a way to pull a single character instead of utilizing a string and then validating? If not, can someone explain why this is not allowed? I think it may be due to classes or objects vs primitive types, but am unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.in.read()` instead of `Scanner`

```
char input = (char) System.in.read();
```

You can also use `Scanner`, doing something like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char input = scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

For using `String`instead of char, you can also to convert to `String`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = String.valueOf(input.next().charAt(0));
```

This is less fancy than other ways, but for a newbie, it'll be easier to understand. On the other hand, I think the problem proposed doesn't need amazing performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, `char` is a legacy type, essentially broken, unable to represent most characters.

Comment: Please remove [plagiarised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) content and your commentary about it - ie "This is less fancy than..." onwards. To make commentary about someone else's answer, post a comment on their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the delimiter so every character is a token:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("(?<=.)");
String c = input.next(); // one char
```

The regex `(?<=.)` is a look behind, which has zero width, that matches after every character.